# List of rollbacks

Tags: support, edits, rollbacks

I wonder whether there is a way for a user to obtain the list of all rollbacks that he or she made on some Stack Exchange site.

The reason for this lies in the fact that months ago someone made a strange edit on an answer of mine and I used the rollback option then. I can't recall anymore which question was, but I would like to find it to try again to understand the cause of that edit.

Comment: Note that if you look in the user's "all actions" tab in their activity page, rollbacks will show with an edit summary of "rolled back to a previous revision" instead of "Rollback to Revision [x]".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just created a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/901785/rollbacks-by-a-certain-user?UserId=446262) which lists the 14 rollbacks you made on Mathematics Stack Exchange. There's an option to switch site and/or to enter another user ID.

[image]

Note that SEDE does not include information about deleted posts, and is refreshed only once a week, on Sunday morning UTC.

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT h.PostId AS [Post Link], h.CreationDate,
  p.OwnerUserId AS [User Link],
  CASE p.PostTypeId WHEN 1 THEN 'Question'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'Answer' END AS 'Post type'
  FROM PostHistory AS h
  INNER JOIN Posts AS p
    ON h.PostId = p.Id
  WHERE h.UserId = ##UserId:int##
    AND h.PostHistoryTypeId IN (7, -- Rollback Title
                                8, -- Rollback Body
                                9) -- Rollback Tags
  ORDER BY h.CreationDate DESC
```